# I want to send email through perl, what kind of setup is required for it?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've tried using these different modules given by Perl for sending email:

- [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aMIME)
- [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender)
- [Email::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSimple)

I cannot figure out whats wrong.  Is there any pre-setup required for these modules to work?

Comment: unable to understand why this question was downVoted, all i wanted was a solution to my problem, what is wrong about my question ??

Comment: I suspect the down vote came from you not including any output of the errors you've received when trying the different solutions.

Comment: It's downvoted because you made no effort to explain what you had tried or what problems you were having.

Answer (score 3):

[Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender) is as of 2009 the best sending module; it needs no pre-setup. You configure the transport, e.g. SMTP, and its options, e.g. hostname, at runtime. See the linked synopsis.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) because it's a standard Perl module. This means it's always available no matter which machine I'm on.

`Net::SMTP` is not quite as simple as specific Email modules, but it still doesn't require an advanced degree in rocket science either.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Watcher-Hook/blob/master/svn-watch.pl) where I'm using it. Look at lines  numbers 767 to 817.